# Spring MVC why my property is null when invoke an @Value property

Tags: spring-mvc

My code as following:

```
public class BgpService{
  @Value("${serviceName}")
  private String serviceName;
  private String fullName = serviceName+"/rest" 
}
```

I do have serviceName in my `config.properties` file, the value is serviceName=10.1.1.1, But when I use fullName the value is `null/rest`, I expected it should be `10.1.1.1/rest`.

Comment: How do you register property file and make spring aware of property file with spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you need to check & fix in your code.

1. From your given snippet you are missing the @Component & @Configuration & @PropertySource annotation

   ```
   @Component 
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
   public class BgpService{}
   ```
2. You are trying to assign/use the value of `serviceName` field on static level (class) hence you need to define the field `serviceName` as static.

   ```
   @Value("${serviceName}")
   private static String serviceName;
   ```
3. And add a post construct method in order to assign value to another field. Currently your initialisation is invalid.

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     fullName = serviceName+"/rest"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Is your class "BgpService" considered as a spring bean? Do you have any spring annotation above it (e.g. @Service or @Component)? Is this class within the "component scan" range? Properties are injected by Spring to Spring beans only.

Can you access other properties from your config file from another class? This will show if your property file is within a classpath.